# How to deserialize nested HashMap structures using Gson.fromJson

Tags: java, hashmap, gson, deserialization

Given the following JSON source

```
{
  "database": "Accounts",
  "groups": {
    "databaseDictionary": {
      "folder": "C:\\Development\\Work\\Ac\\Data\\DataDictionary"
    },  
    "sqlCreateDatabase": {
      "name": "Sleaford",
      "user": "JBarrow",
      "useWindowsAuthentication": "true"
    },
    "defaultData": {
      "folder": "C:\\Development\\Work\\Ac\\Data\\Configuration"
    }
  }
}
```

I was hoping that the following class structure would successfully populate the object.

```
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.Reader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;

public class JsonNestedHashMapConcise {
  private Configuration data;

  private class Configuration {
    private String database;
    private HashMap<String, Group> groups;

    private class Group {
      private HashMap<String, String> settings;
    }
  }

  public JsonNestedHashMapConcise (String fn) {
    try (Reader jsonFile = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File(fn)))) {
      Gson jsonParser = new Gson();
      this.data = jsonParser.fromJson(jsonFile, Configuration.class);
    }
    catch (JsonSyntaxException | IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    JsonNestedHashMapConcise myConfiguration;
    myConfiguration = new JsonNestedHashMapConcise("C:\\StackOverflow\\Concise.json");
    System.out.println("Completed reading database configuration for " + myConfiguration);
  }
}
```

However, while the Configuration.groups HashMap is populated, the nested groups.settings HashMap is null.

I have searched around and found possible solutions around techniques such as  `JsonDeserializer`, `registerTypeAdapter` & `TypeToken` but I can’t comprehend how they fit into solving my problem.

As a bit of background, I have a starting point (source and sample JSON listed below) that provides a workaround but requires a more verbose JSON syntax. It was while writing the supporting methods I spotted that if I make the Configuration.groups field a `HashMap`, it would lead to more efficient queries. I have also read that inner classes were supported in Gson and this starting point appears to support that statement.

JSON source for verbose structure

```
{
  "database": "Accounts",
  "groups": [
    {
      "name": "databaseDictionary",
      "settings": {
        "folder": "C:\\Development\\Work\\Ac\\Data\\DataDictionary"
    }  
    },{
      "name": "sqlCreateDatabase",
      "settings": {
        "name": "Sleaford",
        "user": "JBarrow",
        "useWindowsAuthentication": "true"
      }  
    },{
      "name": "defaultData",
      "settings": {
        "folder": "C:\\Development\\Work\\Ac\\Data\\Configuration"
      }  
    }
  ]
}
```

works with the following class structure

```
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.Reader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;

public class JsonNestedHashMapVerbose {
  private Configuration data;

  private class Configuration {
    private String database;
    private ArrayList<Group> groups;

    private class Group {
      private String name;
      private HashMap<String, String> settings;
    }
  }

  public JsonNestedHashMapVerbose (String fn) {
    try (Reader jsonFile = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File(fn)))) {
      Gson jsonParser = new Gson();
      this.data = jsonParser.fromJson(jsonFile, Configuration.class);
    }
    catch (JsonSyntaxException | IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    JsonNestedHashMapVerbose myConfiguration;
    myConfiguration = new JsonNestedHashMapVerbose("C:\\StackOverflow\\Concise.json");
    System.out.println("Completed reading database configuration for " + myConfiguration);
  }

}
```

The only difference I can spot between the two designs is that the starting structure has an explicit ‘settings’ element defined within the JSON which may be needed for the parser to be able to deserialize that part of the structure.

Am I pushing the Gson deserializer too far or is there some additional code I can add to help Gson complete the task?

### Feedback on suggested duplicate question

The solution detailed in the suggested related question, using a parser provided by  creates a very verbose class structure which I have detailed below (edited for clarity).

This automated parser method doesn't recognise that these related elements (databaseDictionary, sqlCreateDatabase & defaultData) can all be stored in a `HashMap` structure, and I would have been very impressed if the parser could have detected that. Instead, we end up with a class for each and every element.

```
public class DatabaseDictionary {
  public String folder;
}

public class DefaultData {
  public String folder;
}

public class Example {
  public String database;
  public Groups groups;
}

public class Groups {
  public DatabaseDictionary databaseDictionary;
  public SqlCreateDatabase sqlCreateDatabase;
  public DefaultData defaultData;
}

public class SqlCreateDatabase {
  public String name;
  public String user;
  public String useWindowsAuthentication;
}
```

The JSON source detailed at the start of this question is a subset of the number of elements existing within the groups element and these will be expanded (and later searched on).

Using the class structure detailed using  would require that I create a new class to support each and every element (and I expect there to be 10s or 100s of these elements within the source). Using this structure would have also meant that it was very hard to locate a specified group element within the groups element to extract its attributes.

I can parse the JSON source using the primitive methodology of `JsonToken` to populate the java class

```
private class Configuration {
    private String database;
    private HashMap<String, Group> groups;

    private class Group {
      private HashMap<String, String> settings;
    }
  }
```

but, given that the GSON parser clearly can detect and populate `HashMap` elements as illustrated in the second example, I had hoped that a two tier `HashMap` would be detected in the same manner to avoid the repeated use of `JsonToken` as I have other similar JSON structures that would benefit from the use of `HashMap`.

I don't know whether the GSON parser detected the class type in the supplied java class or it detected that there were multiple element names at the same level in order to populate a single `HashMap` as I don't have a knowledge of the internal workings of GSON.

I was hoping that there was a supporting GSON abstract method that I could use to educate the parser into populating the hierarchical `HashMap` class.

### In case anyone is interested

If anyone else wants to model a similar structure, I found that using the `JsonReader` class led to quite a readable solution even though it would be nice if the `toJson` method would have just worked as minimalist code to write. I have provided my source below, although as I am still a bit of a novice, I am sure that there may be more elegant ways to write some of the methods.

```
import com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException;
import com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.Reader;
import java.util.HashMap;

public class DatabaseConfiguration {
  private String database;
  private HashMap<String, Group> groups;

  private class Group {
    private HashMap<String, String> settings;
  }

  private Group ReadGroup(JsonReader jsonReader) throws IOException {
   Group result = null;
   // Iterate over the the list of group attributes
   jsonReader.beginObject();
   while (jsonReader.hasNext()) {
     String name = jsonReader.nextName();
     if (result == null) {
       result = new Group();
       result.settings = new HashMap<>();
     }
     result.settings.put(name, jsonReader.nextString());
   }
   jsonReader.endObject();
   return result;
  }

  private HashMap<String, Group> ReadGroups (JsonReader jsonReader) throws IOException {
   HashMap<String, Group> result = null;

   // Iterate over the the list of groups
   jsonReader.beginObject();
   while (jsonReader.hasNext()) {
     String name = jsonReader.nextName();
     Group myGroup;
     myGroup = ReadGroup(jsonReader);
     if (result == null) {
       result = new HashMap<>();
     }
     result.put(name, myGroup);
   }
   jsonReader.endObject();
   return result;
  }

  public DatabaseConfiguration (String fn) {
    try (Reader jsonFile = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File(fn)));
         JsonReader jsonReader = new JsonReader(jsonFile)) {
     // Root node (database + groups)
     jsonReader.beginObject();
     while (jsonReader.hasNext()) {
       String name = jsonReader.nextName();
       switch (name) {
         case "database":
           this.database = jsonReader.nextString();
           break;
         case "groups":
           this.groups = ReadGroups(jsonReader);
           break;
         default:
           throw new JsonSyntaxException("Unexpected name " + name + "in outer element of " + fn);
       }
     }

     jsonReader.endObject();
    }
    catch (JsonSyntaxException | IOException e) {
      System.out.println(e);
    }
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    DatabaseConfiguration myConfiguration;
    myConfiguration = new DatabaseConfiguration("C:\\StackOverflow\\Concise.json");
    System.out.println("Completed reading database configuration for " + myConfiguration);
  }
}
```

### An aside as my first time posting here

My original question was originally marked as a duplicate and so was automatically closed. I then, as advised, edited my question to detail why the suggested solution in the duplicate question was not related to my question. I then expected the question to be re-opened (as it had been edited) but this never happened. I didn't want to cut-and-paste my edited question to re-issue it as I felt that would be abusing the principles behind Stack Overflow and so I leave confused as to what the correct methodology is to successfully retract a question incorrectly marked as a duplicate.

Since I commented above, I have now discovered (by accident) that I can ask the originator of the 'duplicate' marker to review their decision by 'pinging' them in a comment so I will now try that!

It would be nice if there was an obvious option after narrating why the original question isn't a duplicate on the form but as I am a new user, I can't post any feedback in the general forum until I have 5 credits!

Comment: @michal-ziober I have been advised to 'ping' you having edited my question following your 'marked as duplicate' in order to notify you of my additions as my question is now closed. Thankyou.

Comment: I wanted to point you to other (related in my opinion) question. I had impression solution for related question should work for you. I reopened your question, so, please add a solution as an answer which will be much more readable for others. Sorry, if I could not help as much as you expected.

Comment: Just for clarification, the "solution" I documented above, while it works, it does not solve my initial query. I was not expecting to have to add all this boilerplate code to populate the class. I added this to help anyone else with the same query, albeit as a workaround. It may be a bug or a restriction in the GSON parser